How can I extend an edge by adding vertices?
I'm looking for a way to extend an edge and keep it straight. I tried using double G and C, but it just appears like the image and doesn't move.


Try pressing Alt+S. It will scale it in the direction of the normal. You can also set the Transformation Orientation to Normal and move it with G along its Z axis

Pressing GG and C should work, please share your file https://blend-exchange.com so that we can check.

Select 2 vertices that represent the direction and then press E to Extrude then S to Scale. And then unselect the vertex you want to keep and press X > Delete Vertex. If you want to make sure it is the same length press ES3Enter.

Or you can duplicate the edge whose direction you want to extend with Shift+D and then press B for snapping, and click the from position and then the to position to snap it at final position. Then to weld or merge all the vertices together, press A > M > Merge By Distance.

