Extruding Edge on the same Slope
So i want to make this object bigger on z axis, but i want to keep the slope of the edges(on picture 1). I tried to extrude edges down back onto themselves, and then flip the movement (multiply each axis movement by -1) to get the same slope. i used snapping to precisely snap back onto itself.(picture 4). but it ends up jagged and doesnt exactly follow the slope.(picture 3). Is there a way to follow the slope of the edge while extrusion? 

Do you mean something like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321159/how-can-i-extend-an-edge-by-adding-vertices or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291485/make-line-longer-extrude-vertex-along-line?

First you have to make a custom axis. Pick the line of the thing you want to extrude whilst keeping the slope.
From Transform Orientations (on the left of the Snap tool and probably says Global or Local) click the plus + sign next to Global. This will make that edge a custom axis.
Now click a vertex or an object anything, and click move so you can see how your custom orientation is laid out, the X Y and Z will look different than before, and pick which axis is pointing the actual axis you want to move in, and then you can go back to the thing you wanted to extrude/scale, just press G and X, Y or Z as you decided which one one the previous sentence.
If it still doesn't work, you can set origin to geometry to solve it.
Also, after doing this don't forget to change you orientation back to global, things might go crazy and you might forget you changed it.
